# confindence interval for percentage

Tags: percentage, comparegroups

what is the exact method of confindence interval for percentage in compareGroups package of R?Is it accurate enough to report prevalence[CI] of categorical outcome? it seems that the function is compute.prop and CI is calculate by conf.level

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.